# Select element not posting

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I'm struggling a little - can anybody explain why the select element is not posting for me? The rest of the form fields are posted into the email just fine, it's just the select is blank. 
Many thanks for any help!

```
<form action="/mail.php" method="POST">
<div id=”mainselection”>
<select name="type">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
<option value="four">Four</option>
<option value="five">Five</option>
<option value="six">Six</option>
<option value="seven">Seven</option>
</select>
</div>
<p>Full Name</p>
<input type="text" class="form-inputs" name="name">
<p>Email Address</p> 
<input type="text" class="form-inputs" name="email">
<p>Mobile Number</p> 
<input type="text" class="form-inputs" name="phone">
<p>Postcode</p>
<input type="text" class="form-inputs" name="postcode">
<input type="submit" class="send" value=" Contact Us ">
</form>

<?php 
$accidenttype = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{
    die("E-mail address not valid<br><br>

You are now being redirected back");
}
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$formcontent="Type: $type \n From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n postcode: $postcode";
$recipient = "email@address.com";
$subject = "Email Subject";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

{print "Thank you message"; }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$formcontent` variable, you specify `$type` as the variable to print in the e-mail. However, you named that variable `$accidenttype` above. The variable `$type` is null, which is why you get an empty result.